# Force a developer to set accessibility for all UI elements he is adding

Tags: java, android, accessibility

We have been working on an Android project to improve its accessibility features. We simply set content description or labels for UI elements. But we need to make this implementation a reusable way. Is there any way to make this implement in such a way that, whenever a developer adds a UI element we notice him in the code to set accessibility properties for all the views he is adding? Can we achieve this using an Interface?

Comment: The only way I know to achieve that is **code reviews**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, is right. Code Review is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a maven plugin or find a static code analysis tool that allows you to create custom rules.

Answer (score 0):

[This blogpost](https://www.joecolantonio.com/accessibility-testing-tools-automation/) references [Google’s Accessibility Test Framework for Android](https://github.com/google/Accessibility-Test-Framework-for-Android) which might help you. I went to Assets 18 and talked to one from the Google accessibility team there, they said it is easy to add accessibility demands in the end market place and in the test enviornment.

A paper presented on this conference was about missing labels in Android apps and the effect of it. Here is that study, [Examining Image-Based Button Labeling for Accessibility in Android Apps through Large-Scale Analysis](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3236364), it might be of interest for you.

I'm afraid I have little to none experience of Android development but I know it is possible testing other parts of development and setting up fail/ success rules so Android should not be an exception here.